# (Ubuntu 18.04) Chromium policy JSON not appearing in menu

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I have Google Chromium installed via `apt`. I'm making a custom extension for it, and I would like for the extension to be **enabled by default** and **unable to be disabled by other users**.

Right now, my extension is stored locally at `/home/user/Chrome.crx` and is installed. It works just fine, but it's able to be disabled, and it is disabled at startup.

This is my `/etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/myPolicy.json`:

```
{
    "ExtensionSettings": {
        "myCharacterIDisHere": {
            "installation_mode": "force_installed",
            "update_url":
                "file:///home/user/Chrome.crx"
        },
    }
}
```

(obviously, `myCharacterIDisHere` isn't the actual text in the file)

However, when I navigate to `chrome://policy` in Chromium and:

1. Reload policies
2. Select 'show policies with no value set'
3. Search 'ExtensionSettings'

The Status is 'Not set.' and there is nothing in the value field.

I have tried:

- applying `chmod 600` to the `.json` file.
- Copying the file to `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed` (I had to create the 'chrome' folder.

What might I have missed?